# NPAPI plugin in Internet explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, npapi

Is there any way to make an NPAPI plugin work in Internet explorer or do I need to go the activex way ?

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. The IE team dropped support for Netscape-style plug-ins in IE 5.5 SP2, IE 6.0, and later in [MS03-015](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/MS03-015) for IE 5.01.

You can use [special ActiveX control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ActiveX_Control_for_Hosting_Netscape_Plug-ins_in_IE) for IE, which will load NPAPI-plugin, or you can use [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org).